# Undeclared Property error while migrating data to CRM using Kingswaysoft

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm, kingswaysoft

I am trying to migrate data to dynamics crm using SSIS and Kingswaysoft (v20.2) CRM destination (Create).  When mapping to msdyn_product attribute (guid lookup), I get this error when executing the package:

"*An undeclared property 'msdyn' which only has property annotations in the payload but no property value was found in the payload*".

Does the the logical name (msdyn_product) vs schema name (msdyn_Product) matter?  Also noticed error only shows "msdyn".  I tried text lookup and used another field to map to product entity, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue to us which happens to some very unique lookup fields. Please reach out to us through email, our team could share a temporary build with you which should address the issue. Alternatively, you could switch the service endpoint to SOAP 2011 which wouldn't have such navigation property errors.

Comment: Yes, the change worked.  Is there a difference in performance between SOAP 2011 vs WebAPI?

Comment: There isn't any designed performance difference between SOAP and WebAPI service endpoints. However WebAPI service call payload is generally smaller because it is using JSON data structure while the SOAP service endpoint is using the XML data structure, so WebAPI should be slightly faster. Nonetheless, the issue has been fixed recently, please reach out to us through email to request the temporary build so you can change back to WebAPI again. Note that there are still a few important issues with WebAPI though, the issues are mainly on the server side.